# Select query with constant variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select one of the table column value together with some constant variable. For example,

SQL Table :

```
Key  KeyName
-------------
1    Normal
2    Basic
3    Super
```

Constant values are R1, R2, R3, R4.

The output result as single column:

```
Normal R1
Normal R2
Normal R3
Normal R4
Basic  R1
Basic  R2
.
.
.
Super  R4
```

Appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: How it is related with `vb.net`? Also, explain the version of SQL Server.

Comment: we are missing some info...what does the "R#" signify are they an index of sorts?  if it is just some variable, append it in some fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  T.KeyName,
  TT.ConstValues
FROM Tbl T
  CROSS JOIN
  (VALUES ('R1'), ('R2'), ('R3'), ('R4')) TT(ConstValues)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8e19/1)**

Comment: Thanks, Hamlet. It's work exactly what I want. Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1):

You need to represent the constant values as a result-set, then you can get the cartesian product by selecting from both of them.  For example:

```
WITH ConstantValues AS
(
   SELECT 'R1' AS ConstantValue
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'R2'
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'R3'
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'R4'
)

SELECT t.KeyName, c.ConstantValue
FROM SqlTable t, ConstantValues c;
```

If you want each pair to be represented into a single result, then you can use `SELECT t.KeyName + ' ' + c.ConstantValue AS ResultColumn` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. It's work as expected. Really appreciated. Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT KeyName, Value = CASE WHEN [number] = 1 THEN 'R1' 
                             WHEN [number] = 2 THEN 'R2'
                             WHEN [number] = 3 THEN 'R3'
                             WHEN [number] = 4 THEN 'R4'
                             ELSE ''
                        END
FROM (SELECT KeyName, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY KeyName 
                                       ORDER BY KeyName) AS [number]
      FROM MyTable) A
```